# Jenkins- how to schedule a build to run every 2 hours from 7 AM to 10PM on Monday through Friday

Tags: date, jenkins

I'm looking for a way to run a Jenkins build every 2 hours, Monday through Friday only from 7 AM to 10PM. I got 7AM to 10PM and every 2 hours part down but how would I go about adding Monday through Friday to it?

Here is the schedule right now: `H 07-22/2 * * *`

If I add 1-5 to the above (1 for Monday and 5 for Friday), it gives me an error

> " Invalid input: "H 07-22/2 * * * 1-5": line 1:16: expecting EOF,
>   found ' ' "

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too much element in your cron expression.

`0 07-22/2 * * 1-5` instead of `0 07-22/2 * * * 1-5`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Works as expected.

Comment: Hey max! i have similar requirement. I want to run jobs from 9AM to 5.30PM , but every 2 minutes, from monday to friday

Comment: Can you suggest here please